# appindicator not working after fresh install of 20.04

Tags: gnome-shell, indicator, 20.04

I can't get the `appindicator` extension to work after a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04. I'm using `gnome-tweaks` and trying to enable the extension. It appear in the `Extensions` pane but when I change the switch to activate it, nothing happens. I tried restarting Gnome via `Alt + f2` + `r`, but still nothing happened.

Additionally, whenever I close `gnome-tweaks`, the `Ubuntu appindicator` extension is not activated the next time I open it, regardless of setting the switch to activate it before closing it.

I tried reinstalling `gnome-shell-extension-appindicator` already, but had no success. What can I try next?

Answer (score 3):

Figured out `gnome-tweaks` was not enabling the extension for some reason, but manually running `gnome-extensions enable ubuntu-appindicator@ubuntu.com` activated the extension correctly.

Comment: Thank you for this useful info, but there is a tiny typo: `ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com`. So the working command is `gnome-extensions enable ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com`